# Functional, recursive FizzBuzz in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I was talking to a coworker about over engineering things, which somehow lead to me over engineering the hell out of fizzbuzz. I went for a functional recursive solution in JavaScript. What do you think?

Full disclosure: my knowledge of functional programming begins and ends at "functions are king" and "no side effects" so I would LOVE some feedback regarding functional programming. But please point out other inefficiencies as well.

```
fizzbuzz();

function fizzbuzz() {
    var i = 1;
    var result = [];

    (function loop() {
        var str = '';
        str += fizz(i);
        str += buzz(i);

        result.push(ifFalsy(str, i));

        if (isLt100(i++)) {
            loop();
        }
    })();

    print(result.join(', '));
}

function fizz(num) {
    return isDivBy3(num) ? 'fizz' : '';
}

function buzz(num) {
    return isDivBy5(num) ? 'buzz' : '';
}

function isDivBy3(num) {
    return num % 3 === 0;
}

function isDivBy5(num) {
    return num % 5 === 0;
}

function isLt100(num) {
    return num < 100;
}

function ifFalsy(value, fallback) {
    return !value ? fallback : value;
}

function print(str) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand functional programming in JavaScript this is an excellent read. 
https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide//?__s=85dke4keooezhe18hrzq

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8):

Functional programming is not about writing as many functions as you can. I would suggest to start with a function library (e.g. [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html)) and write as few new functions as needed, taking advantage of *currying*.

Obviously, your `loop` function has side effects: it modifies `result` and `i`.

Without going to deep into FP rabbit hole, your function could look like this:

```js
function getFizzBuzzArray() {
    function getFizzBuzz(v) {
        var ret = R.concat(
          v % 3 === 0 ? 'fizz' : '',
          v % 5 === 0 ? 'buzz' : ''
        );

        return ret || v;
    }
  
    return R.map(getFizzBuzz, R.range(1, 101));
}

document.write(getFizzBuzzArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/0.18.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And if you are going to look at at using a library like Ramda, you might want to look at **[another review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108449)** that takes on this same question and seems to have the definitive Ramda solution.

Answer (score 7):

First, `isLt100`, `isDivBy3` and your other functions are vaguely named. Better name them fully and meaningfully. There's no harm done with the extra keystrokes in the name.

Looking at your `fizzbuzz`, it appears that `loop` is impure as it is mutating something from the outside of the function. You're doing a `push` inside `loop` to `result` which is outside the `loop`. Also, you're mutating `i` as well.

Also, you would want to make your range flexible. Now, as far as I know, functional programming fans prefer a "range" function to iterate through. This makes it easy for iteration functions like `reduce`, `map`, `filter` etc. to go through. Since there's no such thing in JS, [this SO answer provides us one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/575527). It's essentially just creating an array of `n` length.

Next is your fizzbuzz. Since we have an array of numbers thanks to `range`, all we need to do now is just map these values with numbers, fizz, buzz or fizz buzz. We can use the native `map` array method to do that. We just need to provide the number to `fizzBuzzTest` and return it's result to `map` to create our new array of numbers, fizz, buzz or fizz buzz.

*Warning: I'm using ES6 syntax. [Run snippet in browser that supports at least arrow functions.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)*

```js
function range(n){
  return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map((_, i) => i);
}

function fizzBuzzTest(n){
  var by3 = n % 3 === 0;
  var by5 = n % 5 === 0;

  return  by3 && by5 ? 'fizz buzz'
               : by3 ? 'fizz'
               : by5 ? 'buzz'
                     : n;
}

function fizzBuzz(n){
  return range(n).map(x => fizzBuzzTest(x + 1)).join(', ');

  // A non-OOP approach would have the same, except function calls are nested rather
  // than chained (Python)
  // return ','.join(map(lambda x: fizzBuzz(x + 1), range(100)));
}

// SE really needs something elegant to print stuff with on snippets
document.write(fizzBuzz(100));
```

Comment: +1 for the functional approach using ES6. Thanks for using fat arrows to make the code cleaner :)

Comment: `range(n).map(x => fizzBuzzTest(x + 1))` could simplified to `Array(n).fill().map((_, i) => fizzBuzzTest(i + 1))`

Comment: @Pavlo Yup, one of those new things I don't know about yet. :D

Comment: `range` can be simplified to `const range = n => [...Array(n).keys()];`, using more ES6 goodies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to write "pure functional" FizzBuzz, without accumulating or checking the condition twice. Since all of the answers so far use 2+ `if` statements, here's my version:

```js
function fizzbuzz(n) {
  const test = (divisor, callout, f) => (n % divisor === 0) ?
    () => callout + f('') :
    f;
  const fizz = test.bind(this, 3, 'Fizz');
  const buzz = test.bind(this, 5, 'Buzz');
  return fizz(buzz(x => x))(n);
}
document.write(Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => fizzbuzz(i + 1)));
```

Source: https://youtu.be/dC9vdQkU-xI?t=25m9s

It's hard to explain, so let's consider trivial example with only "Fizz" part.
I also removed arrow functions and conditional operators, for clarity.

```
function fizz(n) {
  const fizzer = function(f) {
    if (n % 3 === 0) {
      return function() {
        return 'Fizz' + f('');
      };
    } else {
      return f;
    }
  };
  const identityFunction = function(x) {
    return x;
  };
  return fizzer(identityFunction)(n);
}
```

In this example, execution can only go in one of two ways:

- `n % 3 !== 0` - we return passed function from `fizzer`
- `n % 3 === 0` - we get "Fizz", and execution of passed function with empty string

Passed function is `identityFunction`, therefore in first case we get the number - `(n)`.
Second part of second case is optional, but it's where the magic happens when we chain more functions. If you want to better understand what's going on - try removing `f('')` or changing it to `f('Abc')` or `f`. Or try changing last `return` to `return fizzer(fizzer(identityFunction))(n);`

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Comment: Edited. Is this sufficient explanation?